# Multiple Inheritance in objective C for UITextView Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, multiple-inheritance

I have 2 different custom classes which are the subclasses of UITextView. Now both these custom classes implement special features.

How do you think I can do multiple inheritance and use both the classes to make merge features in one textview.

Or if this does not makes sense can anybody send me a sample code for implementing multiple inheritance in objective C ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't support multiple inheritance. For solving of your problem use composition.

```
@interface ClassAB
{
    ClassA *objectA;
    ClassB *objectB;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) id propertyA;
@property (nonatomic,strong) id propertyB;
@end

@implementation ClassAB
- (id)propertyA { return objectA.propertyA; }
- (void)setPropertyA:(id)value { objectA.propertyA = value; }
- (id)propertyB { return objectB.propertyB; }
- (void)setPropertyB:(id)value { objectB.propertyB = value; }
@end
```

Comment: Hi, What do you think should be the class type of ClassAB. NSObject of UITextview in my case ?

Comment: Seams for me UITextView.

Comment: How do plan to add the implement the delegate methods and instance variables etc.?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_composite_objects.htm small example with explanations.